# Python: Loop through a code with threading

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, line, python-multithreading

I have a code that reads a file, picks a random line from the file and then prints it out with multiple threads. The problem is that whenever I input for example 2 threads, it uses the threads and stops the code. I want it to go though all the lines in the file and then stop the code.

This is the code:

```
num_thread = input('Number of Threads: ')
num_thread = int(num_thread)

def read_tokens_list():
    tokens = []
    with open('inputTokens.txt', 'r', encoding='UTF-8') as file:
        lines = file.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            tokens.append(line.replace('\n', ''))
    return tokens

def read_proxies_list():
    proxies = []
    with open('proxies.txt', 'r', encoding='UTF-8') as file:
        lines = file.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            proxies.append(line.replace('\n', ''))
    return proxies

class Gen:
    def __init__(self, token, proxy=None):
        self.token = token
        self.proxy = proxy

    def register(self):
        print(f'Token: {self.token}')
        print(f'Proxy: {self.proxy}')
def worker(proxy, token_list):
    token = random.choice(token_list)

    d = Gen(token, proxy=proxy)
    d.register()

def main():
    threads = []

    proxies = read_proxies_list()

    token_list = read_tokens_list()
    random.shuffle(token_list)
    tokens_per_worker = len(token_list) // num_thread

    for i in range(num_thread):
        if ((i+1)<num_thread):
            num_tokens_for_this_worker = tokens_per_worker
        else:
            num_tokens_for_this_worker = len(token_list)

        tokens_for_this_worker = token_list[0:num_tokens_for_this_worker]

        token_list = token_list[num_tokens_for_this_worker:]

        t = threading.Thread(target=worker, args=(random.choice(proxies), tokens_for_this_worker, ))
        threads.append(t)
        t.start()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got a lot of code in there that really doesn't do anything.

After rewriting it a bit:

```
import random
import threading

num_threads = int(input('Number of threads:'))


def read_list(fn):
    with open(fn, 'r') as f:
        return [line.strip('\n') for line in f]


class Gen:
    def __init__(self, token, proxy=None):
        self.token = token
        self.proxy = proxy

    def register(self):
        print(f'Token: {self.token}')
        print(f'Proxy: {self.proxy}')


def worker(proxy, token_list):
    # why pick a random one from an already randomly ordered list? "more random"?
    token = random.choice(token_list)

    d = Gen(token, proxy=proxy)
    d.register()


def main():
    threads = []

    proxies = read_list('proxies.txt')
    tokens = read_list('tokens.txt')
    random.shuffle(tokens)
    tokens_per_worker = len(tokens) // num_threads

    for i in range(num_threads):
        # after looking at the complexity here, it looks like you just
        # want to select an equal allotment of 'tokens' for each worker?
        tokens_for_worker, tokens = tokens[:tokens_per_worker], tokens [tokens_per_worker:]
        # why pick the 'proxy' at random here, but the 'token' in the worker?
        t = threading.Thread(target=worker, args=(random.choice(proxies), tokens_for_worker,))
        threads.append(t)
        t.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This basically does exactly what your code was doing - of course, since the thread workers don't really do anything that causes them to wait, they just run one after the other.

What exactly is the problem here? The output:

```
Number of threads:3
Token: t5
Proxy: p6
Token: t3
Proxy: p1
Token: t0
Proxy: p1
```

You've indicated that this doesn't solve your problem - you really just want all the options to appear instead of just the same number as the number of threads.

That actually has very little to do with multi-threading. Your program without threading, file I/O or classes mixed in (which were there for no apparent purpose):

```
import random

# skip the input stuff
num_threads = 2


def do_something(p, ts):
    t = random.choice(ts)

    print(f'Token: {t}')
    print(f'Proxy: {p}')


# skip the file stuff, just some data
proxies = [1, 2, 3]
tokens = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

tokens_per_worker = len(tokens) // num_threads

for i in range(2):
    tokens_for_worker, tokens = tokens[:tokens_per_worker], tokens[tokens_per_worker:]
    # skip the threads stuff
    do_something(random.choice(proxies), tokens_for_worker)
```

Note that this is still the same logic as your program, but with all the decoration removed. And it's obvious why it won't print 5 times, since it only uses one of the tokens selected.

So, a version of the same program that does do what you seem to want it to do:

```
import random

num_threads = 2


def do_something(p, ts):
    t = random.choice(ts)

    print(f'Token: {t}')
    print(f'Proxy: {p}')


proxies = [1, 2, 3]
tokens = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

# only need to randomize once for tokens
random.shuffle(tokens)

# since tokens is randomly sorted, we can now just use them one at a time in order
for t in tokens:
    do_something(random.choice(proxies), t)
```

That solves your actual problem, which is that you do a lot of hand-waving and shuffling, but end up selecting a batch of tokens for every thread, use one and throw the rest away. Instead of doing that, you can just pick one random token at a time.

Comment: So For example if I input 2 threads and I have 20 lines in the file, I want the program to print all the 20 lines 2 at a time if that makes sense?

Comment: Your code and this does just that, so no - I don't see what you're trying to achieve that your code, or the same code with all the extras removed, already does? Unless you feel this doesn't print enough lines - but that's because it's using the exact same procedure for jumbling your source data, for which there seems to be no real purpose (other than randomly printing some)

Comment: So like I input 2 threads, whenever it finishes the 2 threads it continues the codes till all the it went through all the lines in the file. Simpler way to explain is whenever I input the threads I want to loop through the code and not stop whenever the code finishes.

Comment: Are you saying you want it to continue until it has used all the 'tokens' and 'proxies' in the files? But your code explicitly throws them away - please explain clearly what you need. Perhaps provide a simple example in your question, showing both the input (the contents of two example files) and the expected output.

Comment: Yes, I want it to continue until it has used all of the 'token' in the file.

Comment: Well, you select a list of `len(tokens) // num_threads` per iteration, and then pick one at random, so for example, if you have 10 tokens and 2 threads, you take 5 tokens, pick 1 at random and throw the rest away - so it makes sense it only runs twice, since you can only do that twice. Just don't throw everything else out. However, it's unclear what your code is supposed to do in the first place, so although I could just reduce your code to a for loop that prints a list in random order, I doubt that's what you're *really* trying to achieve here

Comment: I don't know how do I explain it, but I just want it to be a for or while loop and print the list in random order without getting any duplicate prints

Comment: I'm sorry, I get that - it's just not clear to me why you're mucking around with threads to achieve that. You seem to have trouble with some of Python's basics (like list manipulation and random selection), but presented a problem that involves threads for some reason - what are you really trying to make that makes this a relevant problem for you? The problem you're asking about is very simple to solve, but has nothing to do with multithreading.

Comment: I already figured it out my own, i'm so sorry i'm bad at explaining But thank you for all the help anyways

Comment: Please either accept the answer, post your own solution and accept it, or remove the question.